# How to hide and show UIButton in swift? For 2 different cases

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have 2 button on UI. If button1 clicked, show case1 button. And button2 clicked, show case2 button.

But cases buttons should be hidden when the page is first opened. It should show whenever button1 or button2 is clicked.

How can I do it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the `.isHidden` property? If not, go to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden) to read about it. Then, try writing some code to use that. If you're still having trouble, come back, update your question with the code you're tying, and ask for help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var case1View: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var case2View: UIView!
```

In viewDidLoad, have below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    case1View.isHidden = true
    case2View.isHidden = true

}
```

Now you have IBAction for 2 buttons. Handle code as below.

```
// IBAction for button1
@IBAction func clickedButton1(_ sender: Any) {
    case1View.isHidden = false
    case2View.isHidden = true
}


// IBAction for button2
@IBAction func clickedButton2(_ sender: Any) {
    case1View.isHidden = true
    case2View.isHidden = false
}
```

I hope this is what you was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two buttons then you should have two `@IBAction...` methods to be called after clicking on that button from UI,
in `button1` action method set
`case1Button.isHidden = false`
`case2Button.isHidden = true`
and reverse for the second button action.